# Scraping a HTML site using BeautifulSoup and finding the value of "total_pages" in it

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm writing a python code that scrapes the following website and looks for the value of "total_pages" in it.

The website is https://www.usnews.com/best-colleges/fl

When I open the website in a browser and investigate the source code, the value of "total_pages" is 8. I want my python code to be able to get the same value.

I have written the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers ={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

main_site=requests.get("https://www.usnews.com/best-colleges/fl",headers=headers)
main_site_content=main_site.content
main_site_content_soup=BeautifulSoup(main_site_content,"html.parser")
```

But then I get stuck on how to look for the "total_pages" in the parsed data. I have tried `find_all()` method but no luck. I think I'm not using the method correctly.

One note: the solution does not have to use BeautifulSoup. I just used BeautifulSoup since I was a bit familiar with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for BeautifulSoup. Here I make a request to their API to get the list of universities.

`from rich import print` is used to pretty-print the JSON. It should make it easier to read.

Need more help or advice, leave a comment below.

```py
import requests
from rich import print

LINK = "https://www.usnews.com/best-colleges/api/search?format=json&location=Florida&_sort=rank&_sortDirection=asc&_page=1"


def get_data(url):
    print("Making request to:", url)
    response = requests.get(url, timeout=5, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Request Successful!")
        data = response.json()["data"]
        return data["items"], data["next_link"]
    print("Request failed!")
    return None, None


def main():
    print("Starting Scraping...")
    items, next_link = get_data(LINK)

    # if there's a `next_link`, scrape it.
    while next_link is not None:
        print("Getting data from:", next_link)
        new_items, next_link = get_data(next_link)
        items += new_items

    # cleaning the data, for the pandas dataframe.
    items = [
        {
            "name": item["institution"]["displayName"],
            "state": item["institution"]["state"],
            "city": item["institution"]["city"],
        }
        for item in items
    ]
    df = pd.DataFrame(items)
    print(df.to_markdown())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output looks like this:

|  | name | state | city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | University of Florida | FL | Gainesville |
| 1 | Florida State University | FL | Tallahassee |
| 2 | University of Miami | FL | Coral Gables |
| 3 | University of South Florida | FL | Tampa |
| 4 | University of Central Florida | FL | Orlando |
| 5 | Florida International University | FL | Miami |
| 6 | Florida A&M University | FL | Tallahassee |
| 7 | Florida Institute of Technology | FL | Melbourne |
| 8 | Nova Southeastern University | FL | Ft. Lauderdale |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 74 | St. John Vianney College Seminary | FL | Miami |
| 75 | St. Petersburg College | FL | St. Petersburg |
| 76 | Tallahassee Community College | FL | Tallahassee |
| 77 | Valencia College | FL | Orlando |